# Convert only certain words to lowercase

Tags: text-processing, variable

Say I have a variable `var` whose value is `fOo bar1 baR2 bArab`.

How do I go about saving into another variable, say, `lc_var`, a version of `var` where all but the first word are converted to lowercase?

I know it can look something like `lc_var=$(echo $var | ...)`, where `...` will replaced by an appropriate AWK or sed command.

Answer (score 4):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
set -o extendedglob
lc_var=${var/%(#m) */${(L)MATCH}}
```

Where `${var/%pattern/replacement}` like in ksh replaces the end of the var that matches the `pattern` with the `replacement`, `(#m)` causes the matched portion to be stored in `$MATCH` (that's the part that needs `extendedglob`) and `${(L)MATCH}` converts `$MATCH` to lowercase.

With the `bash` shell:

```
tmp1=${var%% *}
tmp2=${var#"$tmp1"}
lc_var=$tmp1${tmp2,,}
```

POSIXly, you'd do:

```
lc_var=$(
  awk '
    BEGIN{
      var = ARGV[1]
      if (i = index(var, " "))
        var = substr(var, 1, i) tolower(substr(var, i + 1))
      print var "."
    }' "$var"
)
lc_var=${lc_var%.}
```

In any case, that can't look like `lc_var=$(echo $var ...)` because `$(...)` is POSIX/Korn/bash/zsh shell syntax, and in those shells, [`echo` can't output arbitrary data](/q/65803) and [variable expansions should be quoted](/q/131766) (except maybe in `zsh`).

All those variants turn to lower case all the characters past the first space character in `$var` (making no assumption on what characters they may be). You'd need to adapt it if words are possibly delimited by characters other than space, or if there may be word delimiter characters before the first word.

Comment: Can you explain how is awk able to read that variable and not give an error like "awk: cannot open fOo bar1 baR2 bArab (No such file or directory)"? Thanks.

Comment: @seshoumara, `awk` doesn't process any input when there are only `BEGIN` statements (and optional function definitions).

Comment: Cool! I'm just learning awk. Too bad sed can't do that, my favorite command. I changed my answer to not use echo either, based on that post you linked. I've been using echo in every other line in my bash scripts for years :|, time to use printf then.

Comment: @seshoumara, GNU `sed` can do it with `\L` as you've shown (that syntax coming from `vi`/`ex` initially IIRC), POSIX `sed` can do it with `y` but you'd need to manually specify all the transliterations (AÁÂ -> aáâ...)

Comment: I meant sed can't read a variable directly as awk does in your example by checking the arguments passed; sed always needs an input file, or stdin.

Comment: @seshoumara, with GNU `sed`, there's `echo | VAR=$var@ sed 's/^/printenv VAR/e; s/@$//; ...'` (on systems without a `printenv` command, you can replace with `echo | VAR=$var 's/^/printf "%s@" "$VAR"/e; s/@$//;...'`. POSIXly: `printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed -e :1 -e '$!{N;b1' -e '}' -e ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94709/discussion-between-seshoumara-and-stephane-chazelas).

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`:

```
var='fOo bar1 baR2 bArab'
tail=${var#* }; lc_var="${var%% *} ${tail,,}"
echo "$lc_var"

fOo bar1 bar2 barab
```

as a function:

```
set_lc(){ declare -n v=$1; declare t=${2#* }; v="${2%% *} ${t,,}"; }
```

or:

```
set_lc(){ typeset -n _v=$1; typeset h=${2%% *}; typeset -l t=${2#"$h"}; _v=$h$t; }
```

(this 2nd version should also work in `ksh`, and will handle an argument made up of a single word)

```
set_lc var 'FOO BAR BAZ'
echo "$var"

FOO bar baz
```

More info about bash's weird and limited parameter expansion [modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and about [declare / typeset](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) in the bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: That doesn't work properly if the variable contains only one word (doesn't contain any space character)

Comment: The second version will. There are other limitations -- like not working with words separated by tabs, or correctly handling the dotless `I` in the turkish locale. I'll leave it as is, because the point of the examples was just to demonstrate the use of `typeset -l` and `${var,,}`.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses GNU sed and was tested in bash only. It works even if the variable contains multi-line text.

```
lc_var="$(printf "%s\n" "$var"|sed ':l;$!{N;bl};s:\s.*:\L&.:')"
lc_var="${lc_var%.}"
```

Many thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas for the discussion about edge cases, like echo, sed -z, command substitution and other things.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Updated my solution to treat some discussed edge cases. Since I need the elegant \L in sed, I require the GNU version anyway, so posix was sacrificed.

Answer (score 1):

```
lc_var=$(echo $var | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1\L\2/g')
```

(with a little help from http://timmurphy.org/2013/02/24/converting-to-uppercase-lowercase-in-sed/)